can we move data from cosmos to blob in ADF as separate files?
Update:
Based on suggestion I could save the files and delete but unable to find a way to store the data from cosmos to Azure storage as separate files.
The files are getting stored as a big file with multiple JSON .
What I did was checked preserve Hierarchy:
Sink
Updated Question :
Can we store files as separate files in azure storage folder with file name as ID (received from cosmos).
Option- I can probably use Foreach and read 1 file at time but I assume it will take time and will cost more RU.
Any suggestion ?
Thanks
=======================================================
I am trying to archive data from Cosmos to Blob using ADF

Tried:

I tried using Copy Activity as well as dataFlow. I was able to copy data and retrieve back as well but I am not getting option to move files. What I am getting is copy option.

Question 1:

Can we move files(not just  copy) via ADF and not loose files in case of failure ?

Question 2 :

Can we move files separately ? I do not want all cosmos files to be dumped into single Blob file as it will become difficult to retrieve them in case needed ?

Do you want to delete the source data while copying to sink?

yes after copying if I can delete or while copying is also fine

That means, you want to delete data in cosmos db?

yes after copying/moving

Please read [ask] and how to provide a [mcve], and then edit your question accordingly. Right now you only provided a high level description, and then asked a few questions.

ADF doesn't support move operation. In order to perform move operation, you can use copy activity and copy data from source cosmos dB to sink blob storage. And then delete the source data using rest API in web activity. This way, you can make sure that data will not be lost in case of pipeline failure also.

This is the overall pipeline to move the data from cosmos Db to sink blob.

In copy activity, take the source as cosmos dB and sink as azure blob storage.
Then take the web activity and connect it sequentially (next to) copy activity.
In web activity, give the Request URL as in below image and method as delete.


Request URL format: https://{databaseaccount}.documents.azure.com/dbs/{db-id}/colls/{coll-id}/docs/{doc-id}
Refer the Microsoft document on Deleting the cosmos DB document using REST API

Thanks, but this will solve question 2. If all files are dumped into one,it will become tough to read. Is there any way to copy them as separate file in blob rather than  one big json.

Do you want to copy single container to multiple files in sink?

I have multiple files in container and I want all files to be stored separately in sink folder(azure storage) if possible with file id as filename for easy retrieval

Iterate the files in foreach activity and then copy each container to one file in sink

What will be the value under items in ForEach activity since We can not use lookup or getmetadata for cosmos ?

Ask a new Q with your attempt in this Stackoverflow

thanks ,added  new question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78580297/can-we-iterate-trough-cosmos-data-to-save-it-in-blob-as-separate-files-via-adf
