can we iterate trough cosmos data to save it in blob as separate files via ADF?
I am looking to iterate through cosmos db and store files(to archive) in blob storage in same format as separate files and not a big Json with all files in same JSON.
I tried to loop through cosmos DB via lookup ad then use copy activity in foreach :
ADF Pipeline
Below is the setting for Lookup:
LooKup
and then I used Copy activity within foreach :
ForEach setting:
@activity('Lookup1').output.firstRow
Copy Activity Source setting:
Copy Activity Sink setting

Error:
the function length expects its parameter to be array or a string


do you want to store each container as seperate file in blob?

I want all files in 1 particular container  of cosmos to store separately in blob folder. So ,all files as a separate Json files in blob for easy retrieval as I believe retrieving from blob will be tough based on filter criteria.
